# How to place contents inside two div's floated side-by-side the correct way?

Tags: css, html

I'd like my contents be placed as shown here:

[image]

Inside two `div`'s floated side-by-side in HTML & CSS. I could use some CSS in an unintuitive way to get that but it's practice I don't want to follow.

I would like to know the right way to code this. It it will remove a major hurdle in learning HTML & CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

html

```
<div class="left">
    <h1>jk</h1>
</div>

<div class="right">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">sample</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">sample</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">sample</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">sample</a></li>
    </ul>   
    <a class="logIn" href="#">log in</a>

</div>
```

css

```
  .left{
    float:left;
    background-color:#898989;
    width:30%;
}
.left h1 {
    font-size:20px;
    float:right;
    padding:1px 5px;
    color:#fff;
}
.right {
    float:right;
    background-color:#222;
    width:70%;

}
.right ul {float:left; }
.right ul li {
    float:left;
    list-style-type:none;
    color:#fff;
    padding:0 5px;
}
.right ul li a {
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;    
}
.logIn {
    float:right;
    margin:8px 5px 0 0;
    text-decoration:none;
    background-color:#3c3c3c;
    padding:5px;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/jhunlio/JUdYy/5/)

Comment: thanks for understanding way better than previous replies however I would wait for some more anwers before voting this as the one.

Comment: hi i update my fiddle [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/jhunlio/JUdYy/5/)

Answer (score 1):

```
<div style="float:left">Hello</div>
<div style="float:right">world!</div>
```

More on `float`'s [here](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/floatutorial/), or on [Google](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?hl=en&q=basic+floats+css#hl=en&safe=off&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=basic+floats+css&oq=basic+floats+css).

Comment: I know about floated div's but I'd like to position contents inside the floated div's the correct way. That can be achieved by using margins, paddings or in any other way but the correct way, just not un-intuitive CSS.

Comment: The "correct" way is `float`... not `margin` or `padding`. I have no idea how this code is "unintuitive".

Comment: Pls read again, I would like to know the RIGHT/BEST WAY TO position contents INSIDE those floated div's in an intuitive manner which I presume would involve some margins or paddings.

Comment: @dkjain You're not asking any reasonable question. `padding: 1em` could do what you're asking, but honestly, I don't know _what_ you're asking. Try Googling `Margin Padding CSS`.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 simple ways to do this:

1. Create 2 divs and float them to left respectively:

   `<div style="width: 300px; float: left;">Div 1</div>`

   `<div style="width: 300px; float: left;">Div 2</div>`
2. The second way to do it is:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="wrapper">
   <div id="left">First Div</div>
   <div id="right">Second Div</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#wrapper {
    width: 960px;
    display: inline-block;
}

#wrapper #left {
    width: 480px;
    float: left;
}

#wrapper #right {
    width: 480px;
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: It looks from the screenshot/mockup like there is a central partition between the `div`'s. Your answer uses 2 `float:left`'s, but I guessed from the image it should be 1 `float:left` & 1 `float:right`. @dkjain, which is it you need? Do you want them directly next to eachother, or one floated `left` and the other floated `right`, with a central partition, ala your image?

Comment: I just gave him options in general here. In this case, my second solution will exactly help.

Comment: It's float:left & float:right, however floating div's side-by side/left-right is not my concern but what I woul'd like to know is the CORRECT/RIGHT/BEST WAY TO position CONTENTS INSIDE those floated div's (as shown in the img) in an intuitive manner which I presume would involve some margins or paddings. Pls excuse if my grammar is not very intuitive.